# XCode Organizer Account Disabled (not really)?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-organizer

So i've created an app and was uploading it to iTunes Connect. I was in the organizer and had the app archived, tested on devices, and followed all the necessary steps. When in organizer, I clicked `Validate` in the top right corner to send the source code for validation; however, it tells me `Your account has been disabled. Please contact Apple Developer Program Support.`

When I go to the member center, everything works. I can access iTunes connect, I can manipulate certificates, app id's, provisioning profiles, I could manage apps, but it tells me my account is disabled in organizer. What the heck?

Here's an image with the error: http://tinypic.com/r/30jsh0i/8

Comment: Have you tried to refresh your account in `Preferences`?

Comment: That was the exact problem lol. I figured it out before you mentioned it, but make it an answer and i'll mark it as solved :)

Comment: Also note that it looks like, as a rule you need to remake all your certs, when changing to the new Xcode.